# How much weight can wood paneling hold?

Tags: wood, mounting

I recently moved into a house with wood 1/8 inch panels in the basement. I am planning to mount by TV on the panel (approx 60"), but I'm not sure if the wood paneling can hold that much weight. I would be using toggle bolts to secure the mount, which have enough holding power, but can the wood panel hold it?

I found a number of existing answers for all types of materials, but I didn't see any that matches this scenario (toggle bolts on wood panel).

[image: Wood Panel]
[image: Side view of wood panel]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're asking for trouble if you try mounting a TV on wood paneling.  Even if it holds initially, the weight of the TV will be pulling constantly against the paneling.  Eventually it's going to buckle and you're going to have a pile of TV broken on the floor.

What is the paneling affixed to?  If there are studs behind it, put your anchors in the studs.  If it's against a masonry or concrete (block) wall, put some good masonry anchors into that, and do a pull test to make sure they're secure.

Comment: Yeah, that is likely the best way to go. I've used 1/2 toggle bolts for a TV on drywall (it was solid for 9 years), but it's better to be safe.

Comment: Undamaged drywall is likely stronger than 1/8" paneling, but I'd still be nervous about hanging an expensive TV directly from it.